# How to make template pages in angular other than app.component

Tags: angular

In angular there is app.component.html used to show main html html tags which every page uses.
I have a problem, in my angular project, I have home page ,about us page ,contactus ,features like that.And I also have a page called dashboard. From Dashboard, there are many pages attached. So I want to keep the Dashboard template like in app.component.html. But I have already used the app.component.html as a template page. So what can I do now?

Comment: You can add router-outlet again in dashboard page, add children for dashboard routes and make that possible

Comment: Sure @GvsAkhil. Thank you for the help

Comment: Do u need a sample code?

Comment: If you can I am greatful.

Comment: Ok lemme do a stackblitz... give me a moment

Comment: This should help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: where should I include dashboard routings. I can't understand **add children for dashboard routes**

Comment: For dashboard u can have one more module and routing file, there u can add children, check this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoeZxpfTCXk

Comment: Ok understood .Thank you

Comment: ok :) .. happy coding

Comment: @GvsAkhil can you help me with another question. Sign in sign up pages are totally different from project pages.They don't even use header footer. So how can I build them without app.component.html tags.

Comment: pls post this as a separate question and comment the link. I will post my answer. I have a demo for that

Comment: Ok sure .I will

Comment: @GvsAkhil I posted as a another question. Can you please check it.